# Konva/react-konva is not working with single-spa

Tags: reactjs, react-konva, konva, single-spa

I am getting this kind of [error](https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/1271) when using **react-konva** with **single-spa**. It is freezing my browser(s). I tried multiple browsers but same outcome for all of them.

However I don't have this issue when I am using `create-react-app` or doing react app with `webpack` from [scratch](https://jsramblings.com/creating-a-react-app-with-webpack/). Is it something that might be conflicting with single spa default webpack config or something similar?

This is minimal reproducible [example](https://github.com/EasyBreezy97/konva-single-spa-issue) on github that causes this error. Instructions on how to run are in README.md